# How do i show the result of a method triggered by selection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, wpfdatagrid

I have selected meter which is triggered by a selection in a WPF DataGrid, that part works fine and it returns most of the data i want. now I need the data from a mongodb to but I only want it to connect and query for the specific MeterUID and then be able to show it in another DataGrid.
How do i show Mongodbmodel in a WPF DataGrid?

```
public class Meter
    {
        public string MeterUID { get; set; }
        public string MeterNR { get; set; }
        public List<GSMData> Gsmdata { get; set; }
        public List<MongoDBModel> Mongodbmodel { get; set; }
}

public List<Meter> Meters
        {
            get { return meters; }
            set
            {
                meters = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Meters");
            }
        }

public Meter SelectedMeter
        {
            get { return currentMeter; }
            set
            {
                currentMeter = value;
                MongoDBMeterInfo();
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMeter");
            }
        }

        public List<MongoDBModel> MongoDBMeterInfo()
        {
                var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
                var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
                var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
                var databaseName = "PointToPoint";
                var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase(databaseName);
                var mongodb = db.GetCollection<MongoDBModel>("OCS.MeterEntity");
                var mongodbQuery = Query<MongoDBModel>.EQ(x => x._id, SelectedMeter.MeterUID);

                List<MongoDBModel> Mongodbmodel = mongodb.FindAs<MongoDBModel>(mongodbQuery);
                return Mongodbmodel;

        }
```

It gets all the data I want in MongoDBMeterInfo into MongoDBModel but in SelectedMeter it says that MongoDBModel is Null

Comment: `MongoDBModel` should be your class, so you should know how to display it or not display it. At least I can't see what this has to do with MongoDB, it would be the same problem with any datastore or am I missing something?

Comment: it might be the same problem with any datastore I dont know. I simply added MongoDB because thats what im using here. And sorry I know the question is a bit vague at the moment :)

Comment: have you tried displaying it the same way you display `Meter` in WPF DataGrid? if yes, please post how you tried (relevant codes) and what was the problem with that approach?

Comment: im getting the data for Meter and GSMData from a csv file and then using Linq to get what I want. This happens when i start my program but I dont want that with my MongoDBModel